# Hover/Pointer Media Queries not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I already installed firefox portable with no plugins, still to no avail.
the only peripherals I have connected to my PC are a Mouse and a Keyboard.

Left is Firefox, right is chrome.

[image]

```css
div {
    background: green;
  }

@media screen and (hover: hover) {
  div {
    background: red;
  }
}
  
@media screen and (pointer: fine) {
    div {
      background: blue;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>asdfa</div>
</body>
</html>
```

is this a browser bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, my Gaomon Tablet Driver enabled windows ink pen support and for some reason caused Firefox to assume that my primary input device is a pen, even though it wasn't even connected.

I uninstalled the driver and now it works again

Answer (score -3):

there is no need to do like @media... hover:hover.
why do you need it?
just use div:hover

Comment: What if I'd like my website to look different if hover is supported? For instance, if hovering is not possible, I'd like my navigation to open on click instead of on hover?

Comment: @igorzinchenko you may find this of interest https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/hover